# Count Field Content On Table

Tags: php, count, html-table

[image: count]

I have this table, how to count field content from Count columns (30+15+20) on PHP script?
If anybody has snippet, source code or tutorial, please tell me :)

```
foreach($row->result_array() as $row) {
   <td><div align="center"><?PHP echo $row['No']; ?></div></td>
   <td><div align="center"><?PHP echo $row['Count']; ?></div></td>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize a variable with value `0` ... Than use `+=` to add values to your `$total`

```
$total = 0;

foreach($row->result_array() as $row) {
   $total += $row['Count']; //Add this to your loop
   /* What we are doing here is adding the value of $row['Count'] to $total
      $total value will be available on each iteration and you keep on adding
      values of $row['Count']
   */
?>
   <td><div align="center"><?PHP echo $row['No']; ?></div></td>
   <td><div align="center"><?PHP echo $row['Count']; ?></div></td>
<?php 
}

echo $total;
```

Alternatively most preferable way to do this is to use `SUM()` in your query

Comment: can you help me about substr? how to format this $50000 to $50.000

Comment: That's not a correct conversion, divide the value and use [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) PHP function

Answer (score 3):

```
$count = 0;
foreach($row->result_array() as $row) {
    echo('<td><div align="center">'.$row['No'].'</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">'.$row['Count'].'</div></td>');
    $count += $row['Count']
}
echo 'total count is '.$count;
```

Comment: thanks, your answer is similiar :)